# How to run a Flutter app in the background on macOS or Windows desktop?

Tags: flutter, windows, macos

I'm working on a Flutter desktop application and I need to run some tasks in the background even when the application is minimized or not in focus. Is there a way to achieve this on macOS and Windows desktop platforms? Any suggestions or sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about MacOS, but on Windows there is no big difference between background and foreground programs. So you don't have to care about. Only on Android and iOS running in background can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd use the native platform code to run tasks in the background. For example, on macOS (a more challenging operating system), you can use the NSTask class provided by the Cocoa framework to run tasks in the background.